# Are metric aggregation needed to be calculated by backend?

Tags: java, monitoring, spring-cloud, health-monitoring, spring-boot-actuator

The question about [Alerting Philosophy](https://github.com/Netflix/atlas/wiki/Alerting-Philosophy#alerting-scopes). Most metrics frameworks (`Spectacor` or `dropwizard`) aggregates data, e.g. provide max, min, average etc. So is it true that these data should not be computed by backend? Or in what cases backend should calculate aggrageted data?

Answer (score 1):

Thats an interesting question. I suppose the 'backend' in that Netflix article refers to the backend of the monitoring system. So in a distributed environment, there would be many services(running dropwizard) to send data to this 'backend'.  This is different as the normal backend in 'dropwizard' context refers to the application backend, in the Netflix context, thats merely a 'agent'.

My opinion is that I think some computation could be done/should be done at agent/app backend level.  As You do want 'dropwizard' to do some aggregation to limit the data required to transfer to the centralised monitoring server. And where is no centralised monitoring server, having those percentile metrics calculated means you can serve the data and build alerts directly at agent/one backend level.

Thanks

Comment: `I think some computation could be done/should be done at agent/app backend level` - this is not answer to the question.

Comment: `As You do want 'dropwizard' to do some aggregation to limit the data required to transfer to the centralised monitoring server` - I think passing aggregation metrics across network in addition to others inscreases data instead of "limiting" them. No?

Comment: And the last `Spectacor` and `dropwizard` just only example about metrics frameworks, the question is not about them.